# Nginx - serving multiple builds

Tags: reactjs, nginx, reverse-proxy, production-environment

I am working on large project.
frontend: react + typescript
backend: spring boot java

Recently the codebase starts growing larger in frontend (due to large number of forms).
project
|--> app1
`--> app2

I decided to separate the apps into own different projects.
And Create two different static builds for frontend.

I think I can use `nginx` to do routing for app1 and app2 in single domain (I think its called reverse proxy).

But I have no idea where to begin.

So far I could do `proxy_pass` but it doesn't do import the static assets (like js and css)

I want to know how can I serve two static builds on same domain using `domain.com/app1` for app1 build and `domain.com/app2` for app2.

Any help will be appreciated.

I tried this nginx config:

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name app1.localhost;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; # serving app1
            }
    }

    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name app2.localhost;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200; # serving app2
            }
    }
```

What I wanted to try:

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost;

            location /app1/ {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; # serving app1
            }
    }

    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost;

            location /app2/ {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200; # serving app2
            }
    }
```